# Erro ao fazer deploy no Azure Service Apps

Tags: deploy, lumen, microsoft-azure

Estou com o seguinte problema, estou usando o serviço de deploy do azure, estou tentando subir uma aplicação em lumen ( php ). Até consigo subir porém quando faço uma requisição dentro da aplicação acontece o seguinte erro:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

***Estrutura do meu diretório***

```
wwwroot/
    app/
    public/
    ...
    .env
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por se tratar de um servidor **IIS**, basta criar o arquivo **web.config** dentro da pasta `public` da sua aplicação com esse conteúdo:

***web.config***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<configuration> 
    <system.webServer>
        <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true"/>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
            <clientCache httpExpires="Sun, 29 Mar 2020 00:00:00 GMT" cacheControlMode="UseExpires" />
        </staticContent>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"/>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-Requested-With,Content-Type" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT,PATCH" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Laravel5" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```